# Can't start web services (GeoServer) in OSGeo-live 11 Lubuntu

Tags: geoserver, osgeo-live, opengis

I have created a virtual machine using Osgeo-live 11 in Lubuntu and when I try to start the GeoServer or any other web services they start correctly but when I run it on web I get errors like in the picture below:

[image: HTTP 503 service unavailable error]

I have used this previous package of OSGeo live like 6, 8, 9 and everything was OK, in this release I don't why the web services don't work.

Comment: is that browser on the same machine geoserver is running and did you change the default port to 8082? if your answer is YES NO then try localhost:8080/geoserver/web

Comment: They have configured the port to 8082 as default for this app, anyway i tried even in 8080 but with this port it says "Unable to connect", nothing exist in this port.

Comment: That does not answer the first question.  Log onto the machine and make sure you are not blocking with a fw and that the service is running that error is an indicator it's not

Comment: I didn't manually change anything after the installation, nothing should block the software, i don't even have any firewall or antivirus installed, its the untouched Osgeolive

Comment: What if you use `http://localhost:8082/geoserver/web` ?

Comment: Did you do step 1 https://live.osgeo.org/en/quickstart/geoserver_quickstart.html#start-gs

Comment: Yes, because it is not my first time using OSGeo live, i have used previous version too and everything was ok and all set up

Comment: I was having the exact same issue with OSGEO Live 11. Have you tried running it from a DVD/USB? In my case, it worked on the DVD, but not when installed or run as a VM.

Answer (score 2):

You are being affected by this [bug](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeolive/ticket/2126) - for some reason the user `user` is not in the group `users` so GeoServer can't write to it's data directory. The fix is to run (once):

```
sudo adduser user users
```

and then log out and back in again.

Answer (score -1):

You can start GeoServer in Terminal with the command below

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/geoserver_start_admin.sh
```